# AWS Encryption SDK documentation example

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, encryption, command-line-interface, amazon-kms

I was following the AWS documentation example for envelope encryption in which there is a command for PowerShell. The command doesn't work on my PC so I need someone to help me figure out why. Below is the link to the documentation;

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/crypto-cli-examples.html

Below is the error I get when I follow the instructions in the documentations;

PS C:> $CmkArn = arn:aws:kms:us-west-1:404148889442:key/c6b58e8e-f890-4d97-a417-f5bba5e6af89
arn:aws:kms:us-west-1:404148889442:key/c6b58e8e-f890-4d97-a417-f5bba5e6af89 : The term
'arn:aws:kms:us-west-1:404148889442:key/c6b58e8e-f890-4d97-a417-f5bba5e6af89' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:11

- $CmkArn = arn:aws:kms:us-west-1:404148889442:key/c6b58e8e-f890-4d97-a ...
- ```
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (arn:aws:kms:us-...17-f5bba5e6af89:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax in their example is wrong, this is how it should be written:

```
 # To run this example, replace the fictitious key ARN with a valid value.
PS C:\> $CmkArn = "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:111122223333:key/1234abcd-12ab-34cd-56ef-1234567890ab"

PS C:\> aws-encryption-cli --encrypt `
                           --input Hello.txt `
                           --master-keys key=$CmkArn `
                           --metadata-output $home\Metadata.txt `
                           --encryption-context purpose=test `
                           --output .
```

The fictitious ARN needs quotes around it.

Comment: Looks like this was fixed in the example, Is the official example correct now?

Comment: @Jones Yes, it looks correct to me, single or double quotes is fine.